# Keyboard Shortcuts Not Working When Not in English in 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 20.04

I've recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04. When English is not the chosen language all shortcuts don't work (such as `Ctrl` + `C`, `Ctrl` + `A`, etc).
It was working fine in the previous versions. What happened and What can I do to fix it?

Comment: This has been reported as [bug #1872230](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1872230).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For me, the problem occurs only if "Pointer Location" on the "Keyboard
>   & Mouse" page of the gnome-tweaks utility is set. I have turned it off
>   now and the left Ctrl key now works with all keyboard layouts again.

From bug report [bug #1872230](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1872230).